# How to create SOTAMAS90 DSN?

Tags: odbc, sage-erp

I have a Sage 100 ERP install running on a server and I would like to make a database query through Excel to pull data from the database.  I'm running a 64 bit operating system and when I look in the 32 bit ODBC Data Source Administarator, the only DSNs that appear are:

[[image: User DSN Options[1]]

When I look at the drivers tab, the MAS 90 4.0 ODBC driver is present.

[image: Drivers]

Should SOTAMAS90 be created automatically as a DSN or should I try to create it manually?

Comment: DSNs are rarely created automatically (how could they know the details of your server?), so yes, you'll need to create one manually. Note that 64-bit ODBC applications cannot connect directly to 32-bit ODBC drivers, so you must either use 32-bit Excel, or use a [Bridge Driver to connect 64-bit Excel to the 32-bit MAS 90 4.0 ODBC Driver](https://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/).

Answer (score 0):

Next tab over.  It's a System DSN.

Let us know if you need more help.

Aaron

Comment: Oh, also 64 bit ODBC isn't installed automatically when you install Sage 100.  There's a folder in the installation called WKSetup which has the installer for the 64-bit version.  However, I'm pretty sure Excel will call into the 32-bit version by default.